# Is there a way I can copy logs from one directory to other in continuous fashion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs, rsync

I have a log file in some directory `/A`.
Is it possible to maintain the same in `/B` directory considering the fact if the file in `/A` updates will update file in `/B` also, without re-writing the entire file?

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]! **:-)** Yes that's possible, but probably not what you want.  Can you [edit] the question and provide a bit more background information of what you're trying to accomplish?  E.G. *I have a 1TB DB file and want to copy this as efficiently as possible to slow Cloud storage without copying the entire file all the time.*

Comment: Depending on what you want, a simple hardlink or symlink might suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you can work with periodic updates, you can use `rsync --append`:

```
rsync --append source destination
```

> ```
> --append
>           This  causes rsync to update a file by appending data onto the end of
>           the file, which presumes that the data that  already  exists  on  the
>           receiving side is identical with the start of the file on the sending
>           side.
> ```

If this is not sufficient, you can also try the `--append-verify` option.

Answer (score 0):

I did not tried it but `tail -fn+0` should work. This should work for logs that are plain text files. Program that creates the log must **append** to the file.

(save this to file `copylog.sh`)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

## This script reads log $1 and saves copy to $2

# Usage: copylog.sh source dest

tail -fn+0 "$1" > "$2"
```

Then run `./copylog.sh /var/log/log-1 /home/user/log.txt` to copy log `/var/log/log-1` into `/home/user/log.txt`.

Comment: What if it's a DB Log file and blocks at the beginning were changed? Or the file needs to be copied hourly or...  (see my comment below OPs Q) We need more info, but if your answer gets accepted, please ping me and I'll come back and upvote!)  **;-)**